# If an class implements an interface, and is assigned to a variable with a type of that interface, what type is that object?

Tags: java, interface

```
public class Motor implements Measurable {
  ...
}

public Measurable motorTemperature = new Motor();
```

What is the type of the object `motorTemperature`? Is it Motor, Measurable, or both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The runtime type of the object remains `Motor` even when you assign it to the variable statically typed as the interface `Measurable`. The type defines the behavior, while the interface defines which methods you can call without a cast.

Comment: Your answer is ambiguous. Which is it? "The one taking `Motor` will be called," (wrong) or "The first overload will be called," (right)?

Comment: Wrong. Why don't you try it? The `foo(Measurable)` overload is selected at compile time based on the reference type of the argument. See [JLS, 8.4.9,](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.9) where it says, "the number of actual arguments (and any explicit type arguments) and the compile-time types of the arguments are used, at compile time, to determine the signature of the method that will be invoked... ."

Comment: @erickson You are right, I got confused with the most specific method selection process. I guess I've been out of Java for too long :(

Answer (score 2):

It is a Motor object because your instanciated a new Motor() object which implements the interface Measurable

You cannot instanciate a type Measurable because Interfaces cannot be instanciated. Interface tells that objects that implements this interface, will be able to do x actions

Answer (score 1):

It is a class Motor and interface Measurable. Both are types in a different sense because
separation of Interfaces and Classes is Java way to give an impression of a multliple inheritance, although implementation of Interface only specifies contract.